# How to sort the dataframe by items?

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

I have a data frame like;

```
dataframe <- data.frame(country=c("Japan","Korea","China","Japan","Korea","China","Japan","Korea","China"),
           count=c(4,5,6,1,2,3,0,2,3))
```

Now I want to sort by the country like;

```
dataframe <- data.frame(country=c("Japan","Japan","Japan","Korea","Korea","Korea","China","China","China"),
                        count=c(4,1,0,5,2,2,6,3,3))
```

I tried grouped_by function, but it doesn't work. 
Please tell me how to do.

Comment: @RonakShah Nice base R option, however, it is in a different order than OP stated in the expected output. I couldn't come up with a base R solution myself (only `dplyr`) but am interested if there is one ;)

Comment: you can use `match` in the same way : `dataframe[with(dataframe, order(match(country, c("Japan", "Korea", "China")), -count)), ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the arrange function of the `dplyr` package:

```
library(tidyverse)

dataframe <- dataframe %>% 
      arrange(match(country, c("Japan", "Korea", "China")))
```